# how to return table from mariadb function?

Tags: function, mariadb

i'm having a sql function which returns a table with 2 columns i would like to write the same function for mariadb. I am unable to do it from workbench, its throwing a syntax error so i am trying to do it from linux terminal.

> Create Function testing (numb INT) Return INT AS table tbl(id INT, val INT)
>   BEGIN
>     DECLARATION id INT,
>                 val INT;
>     SET id=10;
>     SET id=122;
>   END
>
> Create Function testing (numb INT) Return INT AS table tbl(id INT, val INT)
>   BEGIN
>     DECLARATION id INT,
>                 val INT;
>     SET id=10;
>     SET id=122;
>   END

I expect the table as output.

Comment: *" expect the table as output."* not possible with functions in MariaDB you can only return simple valid MariaDB's datatypes not records

Comment: If you really need it consider the change to a more mature free database (PostgreSQL) which follows the SQL Standards more which supports returning tables in functions..

Comment: is there any alternate way to do that. Because i have a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL server that internally calls a function which returns a table and i want to do the same on mariaDB.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Is his syntax correct?  And won't `DECLARATIONs` of `id` and `val` override the incoming arguments by the same name?

Comment: @ganeshmarella - What version of MariaDB?

Comment: @RickJames MariaDB does not support returning tables in functions atleast what iam aware off that was mine comment about not about syntax.. i never really checked the syntax because why would i do that if i think/know it is not possible to do in anny MariaDB version

Comment: A workaround for the topicstarter is making a stored procedure instead of making a function which fills a temporary table which can be used in his query.. That is about the best you can get in MariaDB or MySQL for that matter

Comment: @RickJames that syntax is a just a sample one and i am using MariaDB 10.3

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB does not support table-valued functions.

As of MariaDB 10.6.0 (April 2021), the best way to practically achieve this is probably with the aid of [JSON_OBJECTAGG()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/) and [JSON_TABLE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) to pass tabular data between the function and its caller in the form of JSON. The function should JSON_OBJECTAGG() the result set and return the resulting JSON, then the caller can JSON_TABLE() this JSON to get back the original result set.